# Mounted External Drive Doesn't Show Correct Size

Tags: mount, fdisk

I have an external USB drive with 2.0 TB connected to a machine running Ubuntu Server 14.04.

I used:

> fdisk -l

and I can see that my at dev/sdd1. Here is the output:

> WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdd'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.
>
> Disk /dev/sdd: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
>   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
>   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x00000000
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sdd1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

I mount it using:

> sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /media/Backup

And when I use df -h this is what I get:

> /dev/sdd1       190M  1.6M  175M   1% /media/Backup

As you can see the drive size is 2 TB but I'm only getting 190 MB.
I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and linux so excuse my ignorance.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? And a screen shot of `gparted`?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try actually copying a Gb of info there? It can be a bug in `df` only. Did you try reformatting HDD? By the way, check the size in GParted or any other tool that really understands GPT. Re-create GPT table using GParted, the create partition. If this disk is linux-only, use btrfs file system, otherwise you have to use NTFS.
If after recreating GPT you still see small size in GParted, you disk is damaged or fake.

Answer (score 0):

The Error fdisk is giving you is that it doesn't understand gpt partition tables. This means you need a different piece of software the guy above said using gparted but if u don't have a gui u must type in terminal

```
parted
```

after u must type

```
print all
```

This will shows all hard drive info.
This will also all the partitions like fdisk